# Incoming datagram with source IP from different subnet

Tags: networking, subnet

Let's assume two PCs connected to each other with ethernet cable:

```
PC1: 192.168.0.1/24
PC2: 192.168.0.129/25
```

What is the expected behaviour of PC2 in case of getting IP datagram from PC1? If I understand correctly, from PC1's perspective PC2 should be easily rechable without any routing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework question.

You should try it and see. Set up a packet capture and then ping a similar IP on your network. You could configure another host as you describe and packet capture there and see what happens.

So when I have packets destined to a directly connected network, I send them to the right MAC address which I get from ARP.

When I have packets destined for a remote network, I consult my routing table to find the gateway that can get it there and use that gateway's MAC address and send the packet there.

I agree PC1 can send packets to PC2 and PC2 will receive them.